# How can I clone an Eclipse installation between computers?

Tags: eclipse

How can I clone all of my Eclipse settings (preferences, plugins, etc) from one computer to another?

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, Eclipse installs into a folder as opposed to all over the place like most Windows apps.  Have you tried just copying the entire folder?

Answer (score 0):

They are stored in the .metadata directory in your designated workspace directory. So you can copy that over, although some settings may not work right away as they contain absolute paths.

If you are referring to the plugins themselves, just copy the eclipse_dir/plugins folder

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has an import/export facility for general workspace Preferences:

`File > Export > Preferences`

Choose "Export All" and then provide a destination path and filename for your preference file (Eclipse will automatically add a .epf extension).

In a new (or existing) installation of Eclipse import the .epf file

`File > Import > Preferences`

Project specific settings, if you enabled (and configured these), are stored in the subfolders `.classpath`, `.project` and `.settings` inside the project folder. Assuming you preserve your project folders for use by the new Eclipse installation, your project-specific settings will remain safe.

Eclipse projects are also imported/exported via Eclipse file menu:

`File > Import > File System`

see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657884/eclispe-workspace-backup) regarding the way Eclipse uses the workspace .metadata directory