# Eclipse Indigo not working after System Crash

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a problem with Eclipse Indigo.

Last night, when I closed the eclipse, my system crashed and restarted. I have not opened Eclipse again, but everything else went fine. I thought it's just a glitch. When I opened Eclipse today, the "package explorer" is empty. I restarted Eclipse but the problem still persists.

The files and apps are still there are on the hard disk. When I tried to import them, it says they are already existing in the work space and so they cannot be imported.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Try refreshing the Package Explorer. Right click on it and select Refresh from the menu.

Comment: Did it. No use. No display

Comment: Sorry. I'm an Eclipse noob, so that was my only idea.

Comment: Okie.. Thank You. Hope someone can help..

Comment: Try cleaning Eclipse while start up. In windows, Open the run dialog in start menu, type the exe path of the eclipse, add " -clean" at the end and execute the run. I hope this would help you. If this doesn't work try deleting the metadata file in your workspace. But this would delete the default settings and configurations you have done already. Be cautious, because you have to load the projects again.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the link, http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t61566.html

Comment: The -clean option didn't work. Will try metadata option

Comment: Just a question : If i back up the .metadata folder and in case something goes wrong and if i replace the .metadata folder, will it be back to normal (to the current position)

Comment: I really never tried that and I don't believe it would work. Can you read this once, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657884/eclispe-workspace-backup

Comment: @Mohan Thanks for your help. I think i found a temporary solution, I have given the answer below. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the exact solution to my problem. But here is what i did. I created a NEW Workspace and imported the applications into it. Some files showed a X mark on them, telling that .properties file doesn't exists. I cleaned up the projects and everything is going well.