# Can I copy paste the Eclipse folder to another computer

Tags: eclipse, plugins, windows-7

I mostly use Eclipse for coding and have already installed various plugins.
I don't want to install those again and again.

So I want ti know that if I just copy eclipse folder to another computer will all my plugins . SFTP accounts and preferences be saved or they are all attached to operating system

Comment: Related: [Backup Eclipse plugins and settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570160/backup-eclipse-plugins-and-settings)