# Can I copy ADT plugin from one eclipse to other?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Backup Eclipse plugins and settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570160/backup-eclipse-plugins-and-settings)
>   [How to use existing database with Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-existing-database-with-android-app)

I am new to Android development. I have installed Eclipse JUNO and ADT plugin. I found Eclipse Juno so slow to work with. Is it possible to copy ADT plugin files from this Eclipse to another instance/version of Eclipse? Or do I need to re-install ADT for a fresh start?

Comment: Possible duplicated : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2854765/1050058) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4570160/1050058).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is. Go in your plugins folder **eclipse\plugins\** search for everything that has android on it, copy to your other **eclipse\plugins\** folder and restart eclipse. But I never had problems downloading it from Google and eclipse works like a charm for me! Maybe you have something wrong with your installation.

Comment: Nuthing is wrong with installation. Eclipse JUNO is somewhat slower.